# Algorithm for summarizing sales figures

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for an algorithm to summarize a dataset in text form. If you consider below example, which shows sales figures for specific items in years 2001, 2002,and 2003:
[image] 
This has to summarized like below

> For year 2001 ERF had more sales, for year 2002 ADO had more sales and for year 2003 also ADO had more sales. Overall for all these three years AEF had more sales.

Or similar to this to explain this dataset in text form.

Comment: This sounds like a programming question and so off-topic here.

Comment: Can you please suggest me where I can post this?

Comment: I suggest you first write a complete specification for your algorithmic task - what the output should look like. Only then can we know whether it's on-topic here or not. If it isn't, you can perhaps try stackoverflow, though it looks like a pretty straightforward programming task.

Comment: No I have just given an example here. I dont need a Python or Java code to do this exact thing. But I am looking for a DataMining (or something) algorithm (Name of the algorithm) to achieve this kind of work. I dont know proper computing terms for this even. #Beginner

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what is your exact aim. It is routine to generate a summary of the form "For year X item Y had more sales, ...". If you are looking for something else, please explain what it is that you are looking for. We can't propose an algorithm if we don't understand the problem. Modify your question rather than add a new comment.

Comment: Generally speaking, I am looking for a name of an algorithm/mechanism that can summarize a dataset and give its explanation in text format.